# ansible playbook able to send mail via mutt mail

Tags: bash, ansible, mutt

here is my local .muttrc (without names/passwords as XXXX...)

```
set ssl_starttls=no
set ssl_force_tls=no

set imap_user=XXXXXXX@gmail.com
set imap_pass=XXXXXXXXX

set from=XXXXXXX@gmail.com
set realname=XXXXXXXX

set folder=imaps://imap.gmail.com/
set spoolfile=imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX
set postponed=imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Drafts

set header_cache=~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir=~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file=~/.mutt/certificates

set smtp_url=smtps://XXXXXXX@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/
set smtp_pass=XXXXXXXXX

set move=no
set imap_keepalive=5000
```

for testing here is the ansible task associated

```
[...]
    - name: send mail to user
        shell : |
          chmod 777 /tmp/poid.png
          set from ="ansible XXXXXXXX"
          set realname = "XXXXXXXX"
          echo $(date +%Y%m%d)|mutt -e 'unset record' -x -s "Analyse Regime $(date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M)" XXXXXXXXXX@GMAIL.COM -a /tmp/poid.png --
[...]
```

the error messages I got is

```
STDOUT:

Impossible d'envoyer le message. 


STDERR:

L'authentification SASL a échoué
```

Sorry here messages are in french but you guess authentification failed & impossible to send the message

in logs I have in loop from mail.info

```
Jul 19 02:48:21 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: smtp-out: Enabling route [] <-> [2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a] (wq-in-x1a.1e100.net)
Jul 19 02:48:21 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: f34821c26d54d72c mta connecting address=smtp://[2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a]:25 host=wq-in-x1a.1e100.net
Jul 19 02:50:11 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: f34821c17e1ee80f mta error reason=Connection timeout
Jul 19 02:50:11 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: smtp-out: Disabling route [] <-> 74.125.140.27 (wq-in-f27.1e100.net) for 15s
Jul 19 02:50:26 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: smtp-out: Enabling route [] <-> 74.125.140.27 (wq-in-f27.1e100.net)
Jul 19 02:50:26 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: f34821c3c4056343 mta connecting address=smtp://74.125.140.27:25 host=wq-in-f27.1e100.net
Jul 19 02:50:31 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: f34821c26d54d72c mta error reason=Connection timeout
Jul 19 02:50:31 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: smtp-out: Disabling route [] <-> [2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a] (wq-in-x1a.1e100.net) for 15s
Jul 19 02:50:46 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: smtp-out: Enabling route [] <-> [2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a] (wq-in-x1a.1e100.net)
Jul 19 02:50:51 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: f34821c428b472b5 mta connecting address=smtp://[2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a]:25 host=wq-in-x1a.1e100.net
```

in mail.log

```
Jul 19 02:48:21 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: smtp-out: Enabling route [] <-> [2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a] (wq-in-x1a.1e100.net)
Jul 19 02:48:21 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: f34821c26d54d72c mta connecting address=smtp://[2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a]:25 host=wq-in-x1a.1e100.net
Jul 19 02:50:11 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: f34821c17e1ee80f mta error reason=Connection timeout
Jul 19 02:50:11 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: smtp-out: Disabling route [] <-> 74.125.140.27 (wq-in-f27.1e100.net) for 15s
Jul 19 02:50:26 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: smtp-out: Enabling route [] <-> 74.125.140.27 (wq-in-f27.1e100.net)
Jul 19 02:50:26 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: f34821c3c4056343 mta connecting address=smtp://74.125.140.27:25 host=wq-in-f27.1e100.net
Jul 19 02:50:31 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: f34821c26d54d72c mta error reason=Connection timeout
Jul 19 02:50:31 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: smtp-out: Disabling route [] <-> [2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a] (wq-in-x1a.1e100.net) for 15s
Jul 19 02:50:46 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: smtp-out: Enabling route [] <-> [2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a] (wq-in-x1a.1e100.net)
Jul 19 02:50:51 XXXXXXX smtpd[559461]: f34821c428b472b5 mta connecting address=smtp://[2a00:1450:400c:c08::1a]:25 host=wq-in-x1a.1e100.net
```

what I have already tested :

- starttls=yes
- force_tLS=yes
- use of 465 & any other known good values for TLS or SSL
- reading all old messages from here or  https://unix.stackexchange.com
  around it
- change my password to be sure I use the good one
- see logs

the error realy seems to be muttrc side as I cannot sent messages by same command in shell ...

Comment: And those 4 `Connection timeout` messages are normal, are they? I would _guess_ that the upstream is blocking connections to :25 in an effort to combat spam (some ISPs do that, and it's possible cloud providers do too)

Comment: I disable (temporary) secured access for external applications to avoid that

Comment: Using a the shell module when you can use an ansible module is bad practice. Use the `mail` module to send a mail from ansible. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/mail_module.html).

Comment: until the command works in shell it is not a good idea at all if it don't work with shell the next step will be to migrate that function to ansible mail module .... and maybe get new issues :)